# My dark-light-theme toggler does not work

Tags: javascript

```js
var toggleTheme = document.getElementById("toggleTheme");

function toLight() {
  document.body.style.color = black;
  document.body.style.background-color = white;
  toggleTheme.innerHTML = "Dark Theme";
  toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toDark);
  toggleTheme.removeEventListener("click", toLight);
}

function toDark() {
  document.body.style.color = white;
  document.body.style.background-color = black;
  toggleTheme.innerHTML = "Light Theme";
  toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toLight);
  toggleTheme.removeEventListener("click", toDark);
}

toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toLight);
```

```css
u {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<u id="toggleTheme">Light Theme</u>
```

The code snippets are part of a larger JS webgame I'm making. The `eventListener` evidently does not work because clicking the underlined text does not do anything. Not only that, when the code snippets above are not commented-out, the webgame doesn't run. However, when I comment the code out, the webgame runs as designed. Please advise. Thank you.

EDIT: I replaced `document.body.style.background-color` with `document.body.style.backgroundColor` and that fixed the interference with the rest of the program, but the theme toggler still does not switch the theme.

Comment: You have an error on `document.body.style.background - color = white;` and also on the corresponding line in the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is no valid JavaScript code, due to these lines:

```
document.body.style.color = black;
document.body.style.background - color = white;
```

This should be:

```
document.body.style.color = 'black';
document.body.style['background-color'] = 'white';
```

Otherwise you don't have valid strings, and object properties. The same is true for the code in the other function, so you need to update that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Your color values are not strings, and your properties assignments need to be:

- This: `document.body.style.backgroundColor`
- Not this: `document.body.style.background-color`

JavaScript does not use dashes in variable names.

```js
var toggleTheme = document.getElementById("toggleTheme");

function toLight() {
  document.body.style.color = 'black';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  toggleTheme.innerHTML = "Dark Theme";
  toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toDark);
  toggleTheme.removeEventListener("click", toLight);
}

function toDark() {
  document.body.style.color = 'white';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  toggleTheme.innerHTML = "Light Theme";
  toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toLight);
  toggleTheme.removeEventListener("click", toDark);
}

toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", toDark);
```

```css
u {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Color-theme toggler.</p>
<u id="toggleTheme">Dark Theme</u>
```

---

#### Another approach

A better, more extensible, solution is to toggle a class name and keep all of the styling in a CSS file.

```js
var themes = {
  'dark' : {
    listener : function() { toggleState('dark', 'light'); }
  },
  'light' : {
    listener : function() { toggleState('light', 'dark'); }
  }
}

var toggleTheme = document.getElementById("toggle-theme");
toggleState('light', 'dark');

function toggleState(oldState, newState) {
  toggleTheme.innerHTML = capitalize(oldState) + " Theme";
  Object.keys(themes).forEach(theme => {
    if (newState === theme) {
      addClass(document.body, 'theme-' + theme);
      toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", themes[theme].listener);
    } else {
      removeClass(document.body, 'theme-' + theme);
      toggleTheme.removeEventListener("click", themes[theme].listener);
    }
  });
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.add(className);
  else el.className += ' ' + className;
}
function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(className);
else el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
}
function capitalize(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

```css
u {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50px;
}

/** Light Theme */
body.theme-light {
  color : black;
  background-color: white;
}

/** Dark Theme */
body.theme-dark {
  color : white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Color-theme toggler.</p>
<u id="toggle-theme">Dark Theme</u>
```